# Delphi Prism: How to access control(s) on a mainform from another form to update its properites?

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, delphi-prism

I have looked at a very similar stackoverflow question(s), but the answers aren't helping me.

[Updating textbox on mainform with a variable on a child form that is launched from main form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547466/updating-textbox-on-mainform-with-a-variable-on-a-child-form-that-is-launched-fro)

Say I have a TLabel on the Mainform and I have winform A and B. Winform B is launched from winform A. How do you get access to the TLabel on mainform from winform B to update its (say) Text property?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to `MainForm` from `FormB`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Yes I do. I can call its namespace and its winform class, but will I have access to the mainform instance that displays when you run the program.

Comment: Since you will only ever have one main form, you can readily make it a global. I imagine there are plenty of other ways to get hold of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Program.pas, create static main winform as follows:

```
  Program = assembly static class
  private
    class method OnThreadException(sender: Object; e: ThreadExceptionEventArgs);
  public
    class var lMainForm:MainForm;
    class method Main(args: array of string);
  end;
```

In Main method do the following:

```
[STAThread]
class method Program.Main(args: array of string);
begin
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.ThreadException += OnThreadException;
  lMainForm := new MainForm;  
  Application.Run(lMainForm);
end
```